# Converting [Nx1] signal to N separate signals in Simulink

Tags: matlab, udp, simulink

I am using the following UDP receiver block for the Parrot Mambo drone,

[image]

Which outputs an [2x1] array of singles in my case. However, I would like to split the output into two separate signals. What block should I use for this?

Answer (score 1):

It was easier than I thought, but nevertheless hard to find on the internet. The solution is to use the [demux](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/demux.html) block.

[image]